# Starting OpenShift cluster never ends when starting minishift or takes to much memory

Tags: out-of-memory, minishift

Whenever I run the command to start Minishift with the virtualbox driver to the OS host it takes a crazy time and it never ends. Sometimes I even get an error message on storage limit being reached.

I wonder if it is an error of Persistent storage volume configuration and usage that is described [here](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/minishift/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-getting-started.html#persistent-storage-check)

```
mike@mike-thinks:~$ minishift start --vm-driver=virtualbox
-- Starting profile 'minishift'
-- Check if depereccated options are used ... OK
-- Checking if https://github.com is reachable ... OK
-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.9.0' is valid ... OK
-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.9.0' is supported ... OK
-- Checking if requested hypervisor 'virtualbox' is supported on this platform ... OK
-- Checking if VirtualBox is installed ... OK
-- Checking the ISO URL ... OK
-- Checking if provided oc flags are supported ... OK
-- Starting local OpenShift cluster using 'virtualbox' hypervisor ...
-- Starting Minishift VM ........................ OK
-- Checking for IP address ... OK
-- Checking for nameservers ... OK
-- Checking if external host is reachable from the Minishift VM ... 
   Pinging 8.8.8.8 ... OK
-- Checking HTTP connectivity from the VM ... 
   Retrieving http://minishift.io/index.html ... OK
-- Checking if persistent storage volume is mounted ... OK
-- Checking available disk space ... 8% used OK
-- OpenShift cluster will be configured with ...
   Version: v3.9.0
-- Copying oc binary from the OpenShift container image to VM .... OK
-- Starting OpenShift cluster ..............................................
```

What I can do ? I'm following [this tutorial](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/minishift/getting-start) and I just want to get to the stage that allows me to add `oc` to the PATH

#### Update: new error during openshift cluster start

```
-- Starting OpenShift cluster ...........Error during 'cluster up' execution: Error starting the cluster. ssh command error:
command : /var/lib/minishift/bin/oc cluster up --use-existing-config --host-volumes-dir /var/lib/minishift/openshift.local.volumes --host-pv-dir /var/lib/minishift/openshift.local.pv --host-config-dir /var/lib/minishift/openshift.local.config --host-data-dir /var/lib/minishift/hostdata --public-hostname 192.168.99.100 --routing-suffix 192.168.99.100.nip.io
err     : exit status 1
output  : Deleted existing OpenShift container
Using nsenter mounter for OpenShift volumes
Using public hostname IP 192.168.99.100 as the host IP
Using 192.168.99.100 as the server IP
Starting OpenShift using openshift/origin:v3.9.0 ...
-- Starting OpenShift container ... 
   Starting OpenShift using container 'origin'
   Waiting for API server to start listening
FAIL
   Error: cannot access master readiness URL https://192.168.99.100:8443/healthz/ready
   Details:
     Last 10 lines of "origin" container log:
     E0625 14:47:40.905680    2341 proxier.go:252] Error removing userspace rule: error checking rule: fork/exec /usr/sbin/iptables: exec format error: 
     E0625 14:47:40.908353    2341 proxier.go:259] Error removing userspace rule: error checking rule: fork/exec /usr/sbin/iptables: exec format error: 
     E0625 14:47:40.910681    2341 proxier.go:274] Error flushing userspace chain: error flushing chain "KUBE-PORTALS-CONTAINER": fork/exec /usr/sbin/iptables: exec format error: 
     E0625 14:47:40.913452    2341 proxier.go:274] Error flushing userspace chain: error flushing chain "KUBE-PORTALS-HOST": fork/exec /usr/sbin/iptables: exec format error: 
     E0625 14:47:40.919209    2341 proxier.go:274] Error flushing userspace chain: error flushing chain "KUBE-NODEPORT-HOST": fork/exec /usr/sbin/iptables: exec format error: 
     W0625 14:47:40.931698    2341 cni.go:171] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
     E0625 14:47:40.932412    2341 proxier.go:274] Error flushing userspace chain: error flushing chain "KUBE-NODEPORT-CONTAINER": fork/exec /usr/sbin/iptables: exec format error: 
     E0625 14:47:40.938345    2341 proxier.go:274] Error flushing userspace chain: error flushing chain "KUBE-NODEPORT-NON-LOCAL": fork/exec /usr/sbin/iptables: exec format error: 
     W0625 14:47:40.941639    2341 iptables.go:151] Error checking iptables version, assuming version at least 1.4.11: fork/exec /usr/sbin/iptables: exec format error
     F0625 14:47:40.949329    2341 network.go:177] error: Could not initialize Kubernetes Proxy. You must run this process as root (and if containerized, in the host network namespace as privileged) to use the service proxy: failed to initialize iptables: error creating chain "KUBE-PORTALS-CONTAINER": fork/exec /usr/sbin/iptables: exec format error: 


   Caused By:
     Error: Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/healthz/ready: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
```

Comment: In my case it fails when trying to ssh to the VM. I have noticed the VM has the same IP address as my physical machine. Using the command "minishift start --show-libmachine-logs -v 5" to see what is going on, but so far no clue.

Answer (score 1):

If this should anyhow help, the first time it did not finish for me at all too. However the image was in a state "running" in VirtualBox.

The second time I run it via elevated command prompt - and it finalized successfully. But perhaps running inside elevated user did not help, but the fact that I run it the second time.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is that you're stuck on `Starting Minishift VM` (not the case for the OP), then the issue may be that you're on a VPN. Try disconnecting the VPN and see if that fixes your issues.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem. I noticed some network traffic during the first (failing) startup with some slower network connection. I've waited some time until the network traffic was low and tried it again then and it worked. So probably during startup some docker image downloads are done.

Comment: Please add more detail for the answer